# Best Practice for Splitting Large Objects in Redis Cache with .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, caching, redis

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've developed a back-end solution using .NET 6 and integrated Redis caching to enhance the retrieval speed of certain values. However, I encountered an issue where one of my objects is too large, leading to occasional timeouts when retrieving values from the cache. To address this, I've implemented a solution to split the object if its size exceeds a specific threshold.

While my current solution is functional, I'm unsure about the best approach in this scenario. I would appreciate any guidance on best practices and potential improvements. Below, I've included the relevant code snippet for reference, and I welcome any feedback related to this issue.

```
private async Task<SetCacheResult> SetCacheAsync<T>(string cacheKey, T value, CacheType cacheType, CacheTimeSpan cacheTimeSpan = CacheTimeSpan.None, int timeSpanValue = 0)
{
    var result = new SetCacheResult();
    const int chunkSize = 30000;
  
    var serializedValue = Serialize(value);
    var dataSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(serializedValue);
        
    if (dataSize <= chunkSize)
    {
        // Data is small, store it directly
            
    }

    // Data is large, split it into chunks
    var chunks = SplitDataIntoChunks(serializedValue, chunkSize);

    for (var i = 0; i < chunks.Count; i++)
    {
        var chunkKey = $"{cacheKey}_chunk_{i}";
        var (succeeded, errorMessage) = await this.SetDifferentCacheTypes(chunkKey, chunks[i], cacheType, cacheTimeSpan, timeSpanValue);
        if (succeeded)
            continue;
        }
}
```

Comment: are these redis *strings* or redis *hashes*? if strings, have you considered `getrange` (`StringGetRange`)? also note that any time you split the data, you get into consistency problems (i.e. you read the first half, somebody else changes the value, then you read the second half, and you end up with two halves that don't fit together)

Comment: this is actually my first time that I working with Redis, so I don't know what redis hashes are. but What I'm doing is to convert the object that I want to cache to string and save the string in Redis. What I am doing is the split the string while saving and later by getting the value I will than combine all the chunks and after that deserilize it.

Comment: how big exactly is the payload here? how big is "big"? and have you considered alternative serialization tools (for example, protobuf-net), and/or compression (which can help a lot if the data has a lot of text content) (note: timezones mean I'll be AFK until tomorrow now)

Comment: It is around 100000 byte. and the funny thing is that sometimes it function and other times if gave me timeout. I read about it and It say that if I use sync method my timeout is 1 second. and my method was at first sync. and it was written if I use the async the timeout is 4 second. and actually now I'm safe, but this is a magor concern of me, to know how to deal with large data. and if my approach is a good approach and a standard way or not. for example you speaking about compression. and this is exactly my question. is compression better? and is chunking a good practice? as I said it work

Comment: As I say, fetching chunks in separate commands is inherently a racey (i.e. dangerous) proposition; 100k isn't massive, but it depends how much concurrency you have, and what the latency and bandwidth availability is; but yes, switching data format and/or (i.e. together or individually) using simple compression (gzip or deflate) could have a massive impact on that payload size - I could say more if I could see what your data looks like (the shape - I don't care about the specifics)

Comment: Tnx Marc for your time. I combined the two solutions together. For caching Now I have 2 different method, SetCache and SetBigDataCache and in the second method first I compress the text and normally in 99% the cases it get small enough for only one package. I tested a 65K string was after compression only 18K. But after compression I once again test if the value is over 100K if still bigger than limit than I will split. but I think that I will never use the split anymore, but it is good to have it in the method for emergency cases. tnx a lot for your help.